# How do I remove a subdomain that is shared to another webhost?

Tags: redirects, dns, subdomain

One of my team members had a separate webhost from mine and he suggested to host a website from a subdomain on his webhost, we did that and it was all ok untill the team disbanded and now I want the subdomain to stop pointing at his host

have tryed to remove the A dns record from cloudflare and the subdomain stopped completely but when I brought it back it was still on his website, the cloudflare ip was for my host but why is it pointing to his?